# The TCP/IP connection to the host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Permission denied (connect failed)

Tags: permission-denied

I have a web application deployed in tomcat7 on centos7, openjdk8. The web application uses the mssql server sqljdbc4-2.0.jar driver trying to connect to a sql server on windows machine without success. Here are the logs:

org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The TCP/IP connection to the host iam2w19.iam.lab, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Permission denied (connect failed). Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
        at com.arcot.common.database.DBManagerImpl.getConnection(DBManagerImpl.java:60) ~[arcot-common-2.3.jar:?]
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.init(JdbcTransaction.java:48) ~[ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.getConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:89) ~[ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryForList(MappedStatement.java:139) ~[ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:567) ~[ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:541) ~[ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:118) ~[ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:122) ~[ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.queryForList(SqlMapClientImpl.java:98) ~[ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
        at com.arcot.common.cache.db.CacheRefreshService.getCacheRefreshState(CacheRefreshService.java:125) [arcot-common-2.3.jar:?]
        at com.arcot.common.cache.CacheRefresher.readCacheState(CacheRefresher.java:146) [arcot-common-2.3.jar:?]
        at com.arcot.common.cache.CacheRefresher.initialize(CacheRefresher.java:97) [arcot-common-2.3.jar:?]
        at com.arcot.common.cache.CacheRefresher.(CacheRefresher.java:91) [arcot-common-2.3.jar:?]
        at com.arcot.common.cache.CacheRefresher.getInstance(CacheRefresher.java:152) [arcot-common-2.3.jar:?]
        at com.arcot.admin.framework.config.AdminConfigManagerImpl.init(AdminConfigManagerImpl.java:58) [AdminConfigManagerImpl.class:?]
        at com.arcot.admin.framework.config.AdminConfigManagerImpl.(AdminConfigManagerImpl.java:49) [AdminConfigManagerImpl.class:?]
        at com.arcot.admin.framework.config.AdminConfigMgmt.getConfigurationManager(AdminConfigMgmt.java:13) [AdminConfigMgmt.class:?]
        at com.arcot.admin.framework.init.PrintUtil.printAdminConfiguration(PrintUtil.java:60) [PrintUtil.class:?]
        at com.arcot.admin.framework.init.AdminInitManager.initApplication(AdminInitManager.java:167) [AdminInitManager.class:?]
        at com.arcot.admin.framework.web.init.ArcotAdminInitServlet.init(ArcotAdminInitServlet.java:38) [ArcotAdminInitServlet.class:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_242]
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host iam2w19.iam.lab, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Permission denied (connect failed). Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1049) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]

With a simple java class, using the same driver I can connect from centos to sqlserver 2016 on windows without any problem.

The problem appears localized on tomcat but the calalina.policy, with the default configuration, seems ok to me:  in /usr/share/tomcat/lib all jars have all permissions. /usr/share/tomcat is CATALINA_HOME and in CATALINA_HOME/lib I copied sqljdbc4-2.0.jar.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks
Beppe

Comment: Please check question and edite correctly

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out where the problem was.
The problem was selinux enabled on my centos. Disabling selinux the tcp connection to sql server works fine.